# ant - uptodate task : regenerate only outdated files

Tags: java, ant, internationalization, gettext

I'm new to ant and rather used to Makefiles. In a project, the i18n language modules named Message_zh.class etc are built unconditionally from zh.po etc with every compile, although they already exist, which wastes much time. I figured these are the relevant parts of build.xml:

```
<target id="msgfmt" name="msgfmt">
    <mkdir dir="po/classes" />
    <propertyregex property="filename"
              input="${file}"
              regexp="[.]*/po/([^\.]*)\.po"
              select="\1"
              casesensitive="false" />
    <exec dir="." executable="msgfmt">
        <arg line="--java2 -d po/classes -r app.i18n.Messages -l ${filename} po/${filename}.po"/>
    </exec>
</target>

<target id="build-languageclasses" name="build-languageclasses" >
    <echo message="Compiling po files." />
    <foreach target="msgfmt" param="file">
      <path>
        <fileset dir="po" casesensitive="yes">
          <include name="**/*.po"/>
        </fileset>
      </path>
    </foreach>
</target>
```

The target build-languageclasses is depended on in the compile target and so, every compile, the whole bunch is msgfmted again. How should this be written to invoke msgfmt only if 1. the po file was changed, or 2. the class file doesn't exist? I would be glad if this would be possible without further software. Can you help or point me to an example?

A first attempt at solution makes no difference in ant's behaviour:

```
<target id="build-languageclasses" description="compile if Messages??.class files not uptodate" name="build-languageclasses" unless="i18n.uptodate">
  <condition property="i18n.uptodate">
    <uptodate>
      <srcfiles dir="${po}" includes="**/*.po"/>
      <mapper type="glob" from="${po}/*.po" to="${po}/classes/app/i18n/Messages*.class"/>
    </uptodate>
  </condition>
  <echo message="Compiling po files." />
  <foreach target="msgfmt" param="file">
    <path>
      <fileset dir="po" casesensitive="yes">
        <include name="**/*.po"/>
      </fileset>
    </path>
  </foreach>
</target>
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are testing the property `i18n.uptodate` before you run the `uptodate` task. Your condition block must run before you enter the `build-languageclasses` target.

You should reorganize your code like that:

- remove the `unless="i18n.uptodate"` on the main target
- split the `build-languageclasses` into 2 target.
- the first is dedicated to the initialization of your condition and contains the `<condition>` block only.
- the second that contains the code to generate you files (`<foreach>`)

The second target is configured to run conditionally depending on the property `i18n.uptodate` set by the first target.

**EDIT** - Here is a working example of the uptodate task

```
<property name="source" value="${basedir}/src"/>
<property name="dist" value="${basedir}/dist"/>

<target name="init">
    <condition property="that.uptodate">
        <uptodate>
            <srcfiles dir="${source}" includes="*.txt"/>
            <mapper type="glob" from="*.txt" to="${dist}/*.bat"/>
        </uptodate>
    </condition>
</target>

<target description="check that" name="dist" unless="that.uptodate" depends="init">
    <echo>we have something to do!</echo>
</target>
```

HIH
M.

Comment: Thank you. I accepted because your answer contained a necessary step for solution of the problem. However, I still have problems to get it to work. ant -verbose says now when in the uptodate block: [uptodate] (path)/po/ar.po skipped - don't know how to handle it. Why must it handle it when it's only checking?

Comment: I don't have it. Could you post the code? Is the ar.po file uptodate or out of sync when you have this message?

Comment: the Messages_ar.class depends on ar.po but is up to date.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you how it works. The `from` and `to` parameter must be revised. `from` must not contain the folder name and `to` only if it differs. Change the pattern until you keep getting the _don't know how to handle it_ error that means there was an error during the mapping.

Comment: That was it, many thanks! After adapting paths relative to the srcfiles dir, it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ant-contrib - OutOfDate - if you want the structure like in second source in first mail
http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/outofdate.html