# How to perform Delta-Build

Tags: deployment, ant, build-automation, delta

I am creating an Ant Script that will in essence make a delta-build. Instead of deleting the initial directory and creating a new directory, then updating it will all new contents, the goal is to have the script checks the directory, and update it with only materials it does not have, then updating the label.

Does anybody see a way of accomplishing this? I've researched for hours and can't find anything that can steer in any direction.

Answer (score 0):

These should help  get you started.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html

http://www.catalysoft.com/articles/AntUptodate.html

[ant - uptodate task : regenerate only outdated files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601085/ant-uptodate-task-regenerate-only-outdated-files)